# Can an Objective-C protocol have category?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category, objective-c-protocol

Objective-C category can implement a protocol.  Is the reverse true - can an Objective-C protocol have category?

Comment: A protocol can be defined as conforming to another protocol. For example, see definition of `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`, which is `@protocol NSURLSessionDataDelegate <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate> ...`, meaning that it conforms to `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, but also defines its own methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

A protocol can have `@required` and `@optional` methods, which is similar from a compiler point of view (category methods aren't verified by the compiler in the same way normally defined and continuation category methods are).

Protocols can also extend other protocols. For instance, almost any protocol you define yourself should extend `<NSObject>`.